# Working example for aio pika with Fastapi

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, fastapi, pika

aio pika library has a working [example](https://aio-pika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start.html#tornado-example) for the Tornado framework.

Is there any similar example for the Fastapi framework?

I want to run RabbitMQ consumer on REST API defined with Fastapi

Comment: Could you handle it ?